# How to insert timestamp to postgreSQL database

Tags: sql, postgresql, go, timestamp

I have a problem inserting timestamp to my psql database using Go.

I form my timestamp with this line:

```
datetime := currentTime.Format("02-01-2006 15:04:05")
```

My sql query is:

```
SqlStatement := `
            INSERT INTO readings (date, temp, humi)
            VALUES ($1, $2, $3)`
```

And then my call to the psql DB is:

```
_, err = Db.Exec(SqlStatement, datetime, temp, humi)
```

(As you can see I have some other variables here but they are not causing any problems.)

When I execute my code I get this error:

> pq: date/time field value out of range: "21-11-2018 22:19:59"

Which as I understand it means that the format is not correct.

YET when I input exact same query directly to psql console it successfully adds record(line) to the table.

```
INSERT INTO readings (date, temp, humi)  VALUES ('02-01-2006 15:04:05', 20, 30);
```

Side note: This code worked ok before I changed column type from character(20) to timestamp, I even tried incorporating CAST in the SQL but I got the same error.

Comment: It's the `21` that's out of range because postgres timestamps are by default MM-DD-YYYY ... . So just switch 21 with 11 and you're good to go.

Comment: ... alternatively you can change the datestyle setting with `SET datestyle TO dmy;` (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-OUTPUT2-TABLE)

Comment: @mkopriva please put in proper form not in comment.. :)

Comment: @mkopriva I did that already before so I tought it was not a problem, BUT it turns out that I have to execute that sql before each write to the db. Wierd but it works now.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that `datetime` variable is `string` type. I don't know why you must convert `time.Time` to `string` before exec query.
If define `date` column in `readings` table is `TIMESTAMP`, you can exec query like this
`Db.Exec(SqlStatement, currentTime, temp, humi)`

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by adding

```
SET datestyle TO dmy;
```

Before each

```
_, err = Db.Exec(SqlStatement, datetime, temp, humi)
```

So now I have two Db.Exec functions in a row, one is sending "SET datestyle TO dmy" and the other is this one that is sending actual data.

Wierd.